# A fair coin flip, which of the events are independent

Tags: probability

how can i do this problem?

A fair coin if flipped 3 times. If (F<sub>1</sub>, F<sub>2</sub>, F<sub>3</sub>) denotes a typical flip sequence, let E<sub>1</sub> denote the event that at least two of the F<sub>i</sub>'s are Heads, let E<sub>2</sub> denote the event that exactly two of the F<sub>i</sub>'s are Heads, and let E<sub>3</sub> denote the event that all the F<sub>i</sub> are the same. Which of the pairs of these three events are independent?

Comment: Next time, please post what you have tried. =)

Comment: don't even know how to start the problem

Comment: Sure you do. Either you know the definition of independent, in which case you can start writing down equations, or you don't, in which case you know the way to start the problem is by looking up the definitions of the words that are in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\mathbb P[E_1]=1/2, \mathbb P[E_2]= 3/8, \mathbb P[E_3] = 1/4.$ The only two events that are independent are $E_1$ and $E_3$, as 
$$
\mathbb P[E_1 \cap E_3] = \mathbb P[\text{all heads}] = 1/8 = \mathbb P[E_1] P[E_3].
$$